# wso2:cep:Executing Time Window queries on Siddhi Engine

Tags: java, wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I am currently using a Java servlet which has the siddhi core,api and query jar libraries. I am using the SiddhiManager Class to create streams,queries and callbacks. The servlet allows me to run regular queries but doesn't query time window based queries such as -

from StatusTime#window.time(4 min) select cid,sum(values) as SUM group by cid having (SUM>40) insert into payt

Each time the servlet is called the time window get re initiated , as a result time based queries fail.  How do I make the siddhi manager use the previously initiated time window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think initialising and marinating a Siddhi instances (which is a state full engine) in a servlet is a good option. Please move it outside the servlet and maintain that separately.